# Prove that $x^3 + y^3 = 9$ has infinitely many rational solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers

> Prove that $x^3 + y^3 = 9$ has infinitely many solutions $(x,y) \in \Bbb Q^2$.

My approach was the obvious one: writing $x$ and $y$ in terms of coprime integers and then turning the rational numbers problem into an integer numbers problem. But I couldn't advance much.

Also, in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics), a few days ago, some guys helped me using elliptic curves and geometric constructions but, as an undergrad olympiad problem, it was an overkill so I couldn't actually understand it.

Comment: Perhaps there's a pair of continued fractions for which the ratio of every nth pair of partial terms is a solution. Some irrational solution would be the ratio of the limits of the partial fractions. This is just a suggestion; not a concrete hint at an approach known to work.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the 'tangent-chord' construction of infinitely many rational points from a single such point.

Suppose we have a point $p_0=(x_0,y_0)$ on the cubic curve $f(x,y)=x^3+y^3=9$. The tangent vector at this point is given by $$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_{p_0}=(3y_0^2,-3x_0^2)$$ and the tangent line at $p_0$ has the parametric form $$(x(t),y(t))=(x_0+3y_0^2 t,y_0 -3x_0^2 t).$$
The condition for this tangent to intersect the cubic is then
$$f(x(t),y(t))=(x_0+3y_0^2 t)^3+(y_0-3x_0^2)^3=9.$$ If we use the fact that $f(x_0,y_0)=x_0^3+y_0^3=9$ and simplify the above accordingly, this becomes
$243t^2(x_0 y_0-t(x_0^3-y_0^3))=0$. Two of the three solutions are $t=0$, corresponding to the line being tangent at $t=0$; the remaining case, corresponding to $t=\dfrac{x_0 y_0}{x_0^3-y_0^3}$, gives a new intersection with the cubic at the point $$(x(t),y(t)) = \left(x_0+\frac{3x_0 y_0^3}{x_0^3-y_0^3},y_0-\frac{3x_0^3 y_0}{x_0^3-y_0^3}\right)$$
By construction, this is a solution of $f(x,y)=9$. Moreover, if $(x_0,y_0)$ is a rational point then this new point on the curve is also rational, and this can be iterated to produce a family of such rational points. As an example, take $(x_0,y_0)=(1,2)$ and iterate the above tangent-chord map to obtain the infinite family of solutions
\begin{align}
(1,2)
&\mapsto \left(-\frac{17}{7},\frac{20}{7}\right)\\
&\mapsto\left(\frac{188479}{90391},-\frac{36520}{90391}\right)\\
&\mapsto \left(\frac{1243617733990094836481}{609623835676137297449},\frac{487267171714352336560}{609623835676137297449}\right)\mapsto\cdots
\end{align}
In this way we generate a sequence of rational solutions to $x^3+y^3=9$ from one such solution.

Comment: One hole in this, which I don't know how to plug: The above uses one rational solution to produce a second one. But how do we know that this solution is a new one? For instance, one could conceivably produce a sequence of 30 such rational solutions and then find that the 31st is just (1,2) again. I find it hard to believe that such cycles are possible---the denominators seem too horrific for that---but I can't rule it out.

Comment: Show convergence to some irrational solution

Comment: @Semiclassical Both the answer and your comment are interesting from my point of view. But the thing is, why it is related to show convergence to some irrational solution for proving that it doesn't produce an old pair?

Comment: Ressurecting this old question to answer the last comment: if it converges to some $\alpha \not \in \mathbb Q^2$, certainly we can't have $p^{m+kn} = p^m$ for fixed $m, n$ and varying $k$, all positive integers, where $p^r$ denotes the points obtained from the $r$-th iteration (i.e. periodicity) - otherwise, the convergent sequence would have a convergent constant subsequence $(p^{m+kn})_{k\in\mathbb N}$ whose limit is rational, a contradiction. The same happens if there is no limit. However if the limit is rational we can't extract any info.